# HTML submit button's size is smaller than 100%?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, submit

I have a little problem with a HTML form and its submit button:

```
<form action="login/login.php" method="post" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <input id="login" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Nutzername" />
      <input id="login" type="password" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" />
      <input id="login" type="submit" value="Anmelden" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text]#login, input[type=password]#login {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: block;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%; }

input[type=submit]#login {
display: block;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
```

}

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/jMTT3/72/

As you can see, the button is slighty smaller than those text boxes.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543247/css-submit-button-looks-smaller-than-text-input-and-textarea

Comment: 3 elements with same ID? that is a NO NO!! ID's are supposed to be unique per page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default setting is for width to apply to the content box (excluding padding and border). As the padding is different, the outer width is different.

You want to add:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to at least both of them.

Alternatively, you can set the same `padding` and `border` to achieve the same effect.

EDIT: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/jMTT3/76)

Comment: I was wondering for a while why a button width was not getting smaller than 1rem (10px). After reading _padding_ in this answer I tried `padding: 0`, which solved the problem.