# How to turn a DIV into a form element?

Tags: html, forms, css

I'm new to world of forms! I had made divs and css for the exact layout I want for the forms. Is there anyway to maybe just turn that div tag into button or a text field while still using the same css rules so the layout doesn't change?

Here is some code and demo to just check what I have going on.

HTML

```
<div id="loginContainer">
    <div id="loginForm">
        <div id="login"></div>
        <div id="loginUsername"></div>
        <div id="loginPassword"></div>
        <div id="loginSubmit"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="registerForm">
        <div id="register"></div>
        <div id="registerName"></div>
        <div id="registerEmail"></div>
        <div id="registerPassword"></div>
        <div id="registerPasswordConfirm"></div>
        <div id="registerSubmit"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#loginContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 21.8%;
    top: 40%;
    z-index:-9999;
}
#loginForm {
    width:47.5%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    top: 0%;
    position:relative;
}
#login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0;
    background-image:url(../_images/_login/login.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#loginUsername {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: #383d3f;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#loginPassword {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top:30%;
    background-color:#383d3f;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#loginSubmit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 45%;
    background-color:#76c2bb;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#registerForm {
    width:47.5%;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
    top: 0%;
    position:relative;  
}
#register {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top:0%;
    background-image:url(../_images/_register/register.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#registerName {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top:15%;
    background-color:#383d3f;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#registerEmail {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 30%;
    background-color:#383d3f;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#registerPassword {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 45%;
    background-color:#383d3f;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#registerPasswordConfirm {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 60%;
    background-color:#383d3f;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#registerSubmit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 75%;
    background-color:#76c2bb;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[CLICK FOR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7w1adgko/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just replace the right elements with `input` with proper markup, add an opening and closing form tag, remove the borders, and you're good to go:

```
<div id="loginContainer">
    <div id="loginForm">
        <div id="login"></div>
        <form method="post" name="loginForm">
            <input id="loginUsername" type="text" name="loginUsername" />
            <input id="loginPassword" type="text" name="loginPassword" />
            <input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="registerForm">
        <div id="register"></div>
        <form method="post" name="loginForm">
            <input id="registerName" type="text" name="registerName" />
            <input id="registerEmail" type="text" name="registerEmail" />
            <input id="registerPassword" type="text" name="registerPassword" />
            <input id="registerPasswordConfirm" type="text" name="registerPasswordConfirm" />
            <input id="registerSubmit" type="submit" name="registerSubmit" value="" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#loginContainer input {
    border:0
}
```

Here is your updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7w1adgko/2/

**EDIT**: Note that you may want to fill out the `value` property of the submit buttons so that users will actually know it's the submit button.

```
<input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="Login" />
```

or...

```
<input id="registerSubmit" type="submit" name="registerSubmit" value="Register" />
```

Also, in order users to know what field is what, you may want to use the `placeholder` property.

```
<input id="loginUsername" type="text" name="loginUsername" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="loginPassword" type="text" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" />
```

or...

```
<input id="registerName" type="text" name="registerName" placeholder="Name" />
<input id="registerEmail" type="text" name="registerEmail" placeholder="Email" />
<input id="registerPassword" type="text" name="registerPassword" placeholder="Password" />
<input id="registerPasswordConfirm" type="text" name="registerPasswordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
```

And to make it prettier, you could add some colour and padding to the inputs.

```css
#loginContainer input {
    border:0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color:white
}
```

Here is your most recent fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/7w1adgko/3/

**EDIT 2**: To make all the boxes have the same width, you could specify the same box model for `type="text"` and `type="submit"` inputs (source: [CSS: Submit button looks smaller than text input and textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543247/css-submit-button-looks-smaller-than-text-input-and-textarea))

```css
#loginContainer input {
    border:0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color:white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w1adgko/4/

Comment: Thanks that helped out a lot! In regards to the last edit! In order to make the form so when you click on it the text goes away dont i have to make buttons graphics? and how do i get rid of the borders and glow around the form fields?

Comment: what do you mean by "when you click on [the form] the text goes away"? as to the borders, i already provided that in my first answer: add `border:0` to the `#loginContainer input` container...

Comment: OH I didnt see that part! But for example the twitter login page! https://twitter.com/login If you click on the field in change the text color and when you actually type something the text goes away and if you remove all of what you types then the text comes back!

Comment: I added that exactly in my first edit, it's called `placeholder`, try it: http://jsfiddle.net/7w1adgko/3/

Comment: Just did! Thanks again! This will help me with future forms too! :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to start from the proper *functional* markup and then consider styling. For the functionality of a form, you need elements like `input` to set up the controls, `label` to have labels (captions) associated with controls, and `form` to contain the entire form. (And you probably should not have two forms side by side, it can be confusing.)

However, if you have designed a layout in a “DIVistic” way and you wish to turn it to a functional `form` element with working controls, you need to take into account that form-related elements have default rendering that you may need to override. A `form` element has top and bottom margin by default, `label` elements are inline elements (`display: inline`) as opposite to `div` elements that are blocks (`display: block`), and `input` elements are inline blocks that have borders and padding.

On the other hand, most (if not all) of your `div` elements are just containers, instead of being direct counterparts to controls. For example, the element `<div id="loginUsername"></div>` really needs some content, such as

```
<div id="loginUsername"><label for="uname">User name:</label>
<input id="uname" name="uname" required size="8" maxlength="8"></div>
```

Assuming that the content fits inside the `div` element as formatted in your current design, no change in the layout styling is then needed. (However, from the jsfiddle, it seems that you intend to use form controls without any labels. This would be a major usability and accessibility problem, and fixing it probably requires a redesign of the layout.)

Comment: just a slight note, i personally don't find it confusing having register on one side and login on the other, lots of sites do it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the other answer was way simpler and got me exactly what i need! I agree with the other comment. I never found it to be confusing. I also have additional divs on the page to help indicate which side is which! I was thinking about putting in a line down the middle of the two also.